# How algebraic geometry and motives appears in physics?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, non-commutative-geometry, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

First, I'm not a physicist so I have just a little background in physics. I have been reading some noncommutative geometry books and papers (Connes, Rosenberg, Kontsevich etc) and a lot of high machinery from algebraic geometry such as étale cohomology and motives appears in such books, however I could not guess where these structures arise in physical situations. How algebraic geometry and motives appears in physics? Why do physicists needs to use a projective scheme? When this scheme (or other structure) needs a noncommutative analog?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29424/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Algebraic geometry as such appears because it happens to capture important aspects of the geometry of strings.

For instance the partition functions of superstrings are [elliptic genera](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic%20genus) and the best way to understand this is to regard a torus-shaped string worlsheet as an [elliptic curve](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic%20curve), regard the moduli space of possible worldsheet tori as the [moduli stack of elliptic curves](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/moduli%20stack%20of%20elliptic%20curves) or actually as the [derived moduli stack of derived elliptic curves](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A+Survey+of+Elliptic+Cohomology+-+the+derived+moduli+stack+of+derived+elliptic+curves) in [derived algebraic geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived%20algebraic%20geometry) to finally understand that the [Witten genus](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Witten%20genus) (superstring partition function) is but the shadow of the [string orientation of tmf](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+orientation+of+tmf).

Similarly the target space [Calabi-Yau geometries](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Calabi-Yau+variety) of interest due to the relation between [supersymmetry and Calabi-Yau manifolds](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetry+and+Calabi-Yau+manifolds) is best understood with tools from algebraic geometry. Similar statements apply to a bunch of other compactification geometries.

Now [motives](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motive) is another story. Motivic structure enters quantum physics in two dual guises, related to on the one hand [algebraic deformation quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic%20deformation%20quantization) and on the other hand to [geometric quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric%20quantization).

In the first case one observes that formal deformation quantization of $n$-dimensional field theory amounts to choosing an inverse equivalence to the formality map from $E_n$-algebras to $P_n$-algebras, this is explained *[here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization#MotivicGaloisGroup)*. The [automorphism infinity-group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/automorphism%20infinity-group) of either side therefore naturally acts on the space of quantization choices and one shows (conjectured by Kontsevich, recently proven by Dolgushev) that the connected component group of this is the 
[Grothendieck-Teichmüller group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck-Teichmuller+tower), a quotient of the [motivic Galois group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic+Galois+group). Related to this in some way is Connes "[cosmic Galois group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cosmic%20Galois%20group)" acting on the space of renormalizations of perturbative quantum field theory. According to Kontsevich, this explains the role of motivc structures in correlation functions in perturbative field theory, see at *[Motivic Galois group action on the space of quantizations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization#MotivicGaloisGroup)*.

On the other hand, in full non-perturbative [geometric quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric%20quantization) in its modern cohomological form as [geometric quantization by push-forward](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization+by+push-forward) one finds a "cohesive" form of actual [motivic cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic%20cohomology) exhibited by actual [pure motives](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+motive). In effect, a local ("extended") action functional on a space of histories is exhibited by a [correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/correspondence) with the action itself exhibited by a [twisted bivariant cocycle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bivariant+cohomology+theory) on the correspondence space, and the [motivic path integral quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic%20quantization) of this corresponds to the induced pull-push index transform.

This is explained in the last section of [arXiv:1310.7930](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7930) "[differential cohomology in a cohesive topos](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/differential+cohomology+in+a+cohesive+topos)" with more details in the thesis "[Cohomological quantization of local prequantum boundary field theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/master+thesis+Nuiten)".

Comment: More details and more references are on the nLab at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motives+in+physics .

Comment: Wow! A lot of interesting things that I don't know. Do you know from where I start to learning these fancy stuffs (easy reference for beginners)? I just have some little background in Grothendieck's style algebraic geometry and complex manifolds (don't know Calabi-Yau, though).

Comment: For the appearance of motivic Galois groups in perturbative quantization see Connes-Marcolli's textbook http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Noncommutative+Geometry%2C+Quantum+Fields+and+Motives . For the appearance of generalized pure motives in higher geometric quantization see this thesis: http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/master+thesis+Nuiten .